# Flutter getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@959576d

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

Good afternoon.
When i am trying to authenticate user with phone in firebase, google services always returns this error:

`W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 7385): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@5128433
I/flutter ( 7385): Instance of 'AuthException'`

My pubsec.yaml dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.0
```

Answers on the similar questions didn't help.

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: have you enabled google sign in in Firebase console?

Comment: dependency versions have changed a bit since then, firebase_core 0.4.3+3, path_provider 1.6.0, firebase_auth 0.15.4, if anyone else still has issues, please post a sample.